# Mean and median of a linear piecewise pdf

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, probability-distributions

I am studying for a test and I was wondering what is the mean and median of any linear piecewise pdf and why. Also just so you know p.d.f is probability density function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the definition for the mean and median. We have for the mean:

$$\mu=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)\:\mathrm{d}x$$

Where $f(x)$ is the PDF of the distribution. Therefore if you have a piecewise function, e.g:

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}ax^{2}+bx+c & x\in[0,1] \\ dx + e & x\in(1,10) \\ 0 & x\not\in [1,10)\end{cases}$$

Where $a,b,c,d,e\in\mathbb{R}$, such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)\:\mathrm{d}x=1$. We would just compute:

$$\mu = \int_{0}^{1}x(ax^{2}+bx+c)\:\mathrm{d}x+\int_{1}^{10}x(dx+e)\:\mathrm{d}x$$

For the median $Q_{2}$ our definition is:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{Q_{2}}f(x)\:\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}$$

Therefore a good idea is to compute the integrals for each of the pieces (i.e. $\int_{0}^{1}(ax^{2}+bx+c)\:\mathrm{d}x$ and $\int_{1}^{10}(dx+e)\:\mathrm{d}x$) to see in which region the median lies and then compute it in the usual way.

Comment: what if the distribution is unifom

Comment: Then you simply have $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{b-a} & x \in [a,b] \\ 0 & k \not\in [a,b]\end{cases}$$ And you perform the same computations?